# Combobox enable ctrl+a to select text

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I would like to enable ctrl+a to select the text within a combobox. Instead of selecting all it does <end> (more or less at least).

minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

root = tk.Tk()


def month_changed(event):
    msg = f'You selected {month_cb.get()}!'
    showinfo(title='Result', message=msg)


# month of year
months = ['Jan', 'Feb']

# create a combobox
selected_month = tk.StringVar()

month_cb = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=selected_month)
month_cb['values'] = months
month_cb.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

month_cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', month_changed)
month_cb.bind('<Control-a>', doSomeSelecting) #doSomeSelcting tbd
root.mainloop()
```

I stole the example and minimized it from here to get a quick example: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-combobox/

Comment: What is "strg+a"?

Comment: @BryanOakley It's Ctrl+A (strg is short for Steuerung which is German for control)

Comment: I don't see where you're attempting to bind to control-a. Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I could add an attempt - if it would make you happy @BryanOakley - but I have no clue how to start. I know how to bind the key to a function, but I don't know how I can affect the selection of text.

Comment: I added the binding so we can only discuss the selecting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are doing is overriding the default bindings for your platform. On X11 Tk sets up a default binding for `Control-Key-slash` to generate the `<<SelectAll>>` virtual event. On Win32 this is extended with `Control-Key-a` as well. On X11 Control-a is bound to `<<LineStart>>`.

So the platfrom correct thing is to leave it alone and learn to use Control-slash to select all. To override this you need to bind Control-a to a function that generates the SelectAll virtual event *and also* prevents the default event handler from then moving the insertion point to the start of the line. For that:

```
def selall(ev):
    ev.widget.event_generate('<<SelectAll>>')
    return 'break'

month_cb.bind('<Control-a>', selall)
```

The `return 'break'` is important here otherwise the event handlers will continue being called and our selection will be undone when something generates the `<<LineStart>>` event after our `<<SelectAll>>`.

This can be investigated in IDLE using `month_cb.bindtags()` to find that it's class bindings are TCombobox. Then `month_cb.bind_class('TCombobox')` to see all the events that are bound to this class. For the virtual events, `root.event_info('<<SelectAll>>')` shows the set of events that cause this virtual event to be raised.